# A transparent window that ignores mouse events with wxWidgets or with any other C++ cross-platform library

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt, wxwidgets

I would like to know if it is possible to create a transparent window that ignores mouse events. My goal is to create a "glass pane" and put it on another window. Mouse events should be received from the covered window.
 [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) example does it, but I would like to use a C++ library like wxWidgets or Qt. 
I already tried to create a transparent window with those libraries but without success.
Has anybody tried to create a window with these features? 
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: This is likely to be OS specific. Which OS are you interested in?

Comment: Ah .. Objective C .. so presumably OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore mouse events - but it's upto the OS to decide which application to send the mouse event to and it's unlikely to propogate it to another app that is underneath your app.

Unless your operating system has a specific option to do this then other than some sort of hook in the graphics driver so that the OS doesn't know your window is there I can't see an obvious way